# Copy block between objects

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, nscopying

I've always thought, that `copy` would just copy the object. In case of blocks, it's a bit different, but I'm really surprised how it works in following case.

I have and instance `objectA` and `objectB` of the following class:

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject
@property(nonatomic, copy) void (^myHandler)(CGFloat progress);
@property(nonatomic) CGFloat progress;
@end
```

`objectA` is empty. `objectB` has the values set. In some point of app, I want to discard `objectB` and leave only `objectA`, so I need to inject these two values of `objectB` to `objectA`:

```
MyObject *objectA = [MyObject new];
if (nowIWantToGetRidOfB) {
    objectA.progress = objectB.progress;
    objectA.myHandler = objectB.myHandler;
    objectB.myHandler = nil;
    objectB = nil; // that's just an example to show it gets released after this code
}
```

I'd expect the block to be copied to the new `objectA` instance and `objectB` to be released (because there is no reference pointing to it).

But instead, nothing happens. The block, even though it should, is never again evaluated. Should I copy it in another way? Can someone explain what's and why is happening or point to some documentation which will explain it?

-- edit --

Snippet how the block is set:

```
MyObject *objectB = [MyObject new];
objectB.progress = 0.5f;
[objectB setProgressHandler:^(CGFloat progress) {
    NSLog(@"example");
}];
```

Comment: Update your question with the code that uses the `myHandler` property on `objectA`.

Comment: Don't use blocks with objects. It's bad practice of developers that come to objective-c from javascript. In your's case you need `delegate`. Block should be used only as callbacks for async methods.

Comment: Can you show the code that creates/assigns the handler to objectB so we can see how it is used.

Comment: I think your code snippets are not enough to solve the problem. when is objectB made?

Comment: @Cy-4AH I would not say it that strict, but indeed, blocks are chosen over delegates too often.

Comment: What is the content of the block? Does it refer `objectB` (via `self`) strongly?

Comment: I prefer blocks in such cases. Delegates aren't so comfortable to work with nor so readable, and it's one of most important features of code to be easily maintainable by people, who don't know the project. Seems it's a personal preference and we can debate here which is better - what won't help me to solve the problem :) I've updated the snippet with requested code.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad No, it doesn't use `objectB` at all. Even if, there should be weak reference instead of strong to avoid retain cycle.

Comment: Your update still doesn't show how you make use of the `myHandler` property on `objectA` after doing the copy.

Comment: @Vive Indeed, you wrote that `objectB` is not released. ;-) This looks like a retain cycle. If you do not set the handler, is the object released?

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad `ObjectB` is not released because I want to keep it - so it's saved in a strong property in `viewModel` class. If I'd nil it, it would be released, so it's not a retain cycle.

Comment: Ah, okay, you wrote *objectB to be released (because there is no reference pointing to it).* Can you add the call to the handler?

Answer (score 1):

Beside the question in my comment, this likely does not work anyway.

Blocks are not only a snippet of code, but closures. That means that they do a snapshot of the point in time they are created. If such a block refers to `objectB` at creation time, after copying they will still refer to that object, even you store the block or a copy of it to `objectA`. (Instance objects does not have identifiers, however, I think I understand what you mean.)

So, having this code:

```
MyObject *objectB = …;
objectB.handler = ^(CGFloat progress)
{
  … objectB …
}
```

Something will be done with `objectB`. After copying (here explicitly) …

```
MyObject *objectA = …;
objectA.handler = objectB.handler;
```

… it is still the same: Something will be done with *`objectB`*, because it is still referred by the block.

Comment: Even having simple NSLog inside the block, so not using `objectB` finished the way I've described. I've finished with just replacing the whole object with block inside and it's fully working.